# Java - How can I most-efficiently sort an array of SomeClass objects by a String field in those objects?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a class which has a String field called `name`. I have an array of type `SomeClass[]` and I want to iterate through these `SomeClass` objects in String order on their names.

I'm curious as to what the most efficient way to do this would be. Should I use a comparator of some sort? Would it be a good idea to put them all into a `TreeMap` and then iterate through that or something similar? I'm sure I could come up with a solution, but I'm also sure that it would be less than efficient.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As per my understanding, you want to sort the class objects according to their name fields. is it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your Classes in an `Arraylist` and use its `sort` method.
Unverified code:

```
yourArray.sort(new YourNameComparator());

class YourNameComparator implements Comparator<YourNameClass> {
    int compare(YourNameClass y1, YourNameClass y2) {
        return y1.getName().compareTo(y2.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: this is more what I was looking for as I couldn't change the SomeClass class, and didn't want to have to subclass it. I ended up doing this but just with an anonymous Comparator class right in the sort() call. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can just `Arrays.sort` your `Comparable` class, like `Arrays.sort(a)` (see the code)

Or, if you wanted to use Collections framework

`Arrays.asList(...)` and `Collections.sort(..)` is the key.

---

IF SomeClass is like this

```
public class SomeClass implements Comparable<SomeClass>{

    public String val;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SomeClass that) {
        return this.val.compareTo(that.val);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.val;
    }
}
```

yo can sort like this

```
    SomeClass o = new SomeClass();
    o.val = "z";
    SomeClass t = new SomeClass();
    t.val = "a";
    SomeClass th = new SomeClass();
    th.val = "m";
    SomeClass[] a = new SomeClass[]{o, t, th};

    //this
    Arrays.sort(a);

    //or this
    List<SomeClass> l = Arrays.asList(a);
    System.out.println(l);
    Collections.sort(l);
    System.out.println(l);
```

Comment: @programmer_1 for sake of simplicity I have made the attribute public. :) It serves the purpose for example.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your best bet would be to, as you say, put it in a TreeMap (or some data structure that sorts it for you) and then read it out already sorted. There's hardly a way to get faster, and this way would produce the cleanest and most readable code.

Answer (score 1):

Your two options: have your class implement comparable and write a compareTo method or create a comparator and feed that into Collections.sort(List list, Comparator c)

Since you want to compare strings, you probably want to use comparable since StringY.compareTo(String x) already exists.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html