# Sorting an array (Object[]) consisting of integers and strings - Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have and array of type Object[], containing integers and strings (single letters).

```
Object[] myArray = {(String) "U", (String) "U", (int) 2, (String) "X", (int) 4, (String) "U"};
```

What my question is, is there a simple way to sort this array, firstly by ints before strings and secondly by ints in numerical ascending order and string in alphabetical order?
I was looking for something similar to the Arrays.sort method, but i don't think it will be that simple.

Thank you

Comment: There is no point of having this, just create char array or string array and you can sort it with Arrays.sort.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! May I ask that you elaborate? I'm fairly new to Java, but from what i gather your suggestion may not work? i.e having ints in a String array (as you suggested) would not work? @libik

Comment: @user3636636 Having a sequence of *heterogeneous* types often indicates of a design issue.

Comment: Why do you cast String literals to `String` and integer literals to `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to provide a `Comparator<Object>` instance and check the type of the objects to determine their sorting:

```
Arrays.sort(myArray, new IntStringComparator());

//...

public static class IntStringComparator implements Comparator<Object> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        if (o1 == null) {
            return -1; // o1 is null, should be less than any value 
        }
        if(o2 == null){
            return 1; // o2 is null, should be less than any non-null value
        }
        if (o1 instanceof Integer) {
            if (o2 instanceof Integer) {
                return Integer.compare((int) o1, (int) o2); // Compare by int
            } else {
                return -1; // int < String
            }
        } else {
            if (o2 instanceof String) {
                return ((String) o1).compareTo((String) o2); // Compare by string
            } else {
                return 1; // String > int
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
[2, 4, U, U, U, X]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8:

```
    Object[] myArray = {(String) "U", (String) "U", (int) 2, (String) "X", (int) 4, (String) "U"};
    Stream.of(myArray).filter(x -> !(x instanceof String))
            .sorted().forEach(System.out::print);
    Stream.of(myArray).filter(x -> x instanceof String)
                        .sorted().forEach(System.out::print);
```

For David Wallace: in case you want to save the sorted array (I save it to List in this example but it can be converted into `.toArray()` if you want):

```
    Object[] myArray = {(String) "U", (String) "U", (int) 2, (String) "X", (int) 4, (String) "U"};
    List<Object> newList = Stream.of(myArray).filter(x -> x instanceof String)
                        .sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.addAll(newList, Stream.of(myArray).filter(x -> !(x instanceof String))
            .sorted().toArray());

    for (Object o : newList) {
        System.out.print(o);
    }
```

**OUTPUT** (of both code snippets):

```
24UUUX
```

That said, it's a bad practice to mix different types in the same array (to use `Object` like you did). Different types should be "mixed" only if they have an interface in common (or, if one of them extends the other )!

Comment: The OP requested `int`s before `String`s in the output.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! very helpful. 
May you suggest a better data structure to hold the given ints and strings, given that what i have done is bad practice? Thank you @alfasin

Comment: @user3636636 well.. the point is not to offer a different data-structure, the point is that different types *should not* be mixed! If there is a common meaning, there should be an object that wraps them and reflects this property. But since I don't know what was the intention behind this exercise - I can't find a common property that ints and strings share.

Comment: Nice usage of `Stream`s. Ironically, they almost make static typing seem meaningless here!

Comment: This isn't actually sorting the array is it?  You never ended up with an array that had the numbers then the letters, sorted in that order.

Comment: @DavidWallace see the addition part

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the function to use to compare objects, and so make it behave however you like.  For an example, see [Java - How can I most-efficiently sort an array of SomeClass objects by a String field in those objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9426087/535275)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go is to create a Generic Class which will implement the Comparable interface. Such that you can store any type in a Array and having a compare method to do what ever you want.